# Summarize unique combination of field values found in table

Tags: sql, oracle, dbeaver

How to summarize how many records are returned from all combinations of 2 fields, where each field has 3 possible values (`Y`,`N`,`NULL`)?

The target is a table like the below and a query to quickly regenerate it so we can validate the clean up effort. (ie. restricted AND explicitly not confidential is an invalid status, those records need to be investigated). It's important to know which combinations return zero records. Not having all combinations present in the example is an oversight (and provides of a demonstration for why seeking a non-manual solution is a good idea!).

I know how to get each row of the results table separately but not in one go. The source DB is read-only, so I can't create views or new tables. I'm using Dbeaver for my analysis.

```
SELECT x.*,x.ROWID FROM table.PROJECT x
WHERE CONFIDENTIAL = 'Y'
```

then

```
SELECT x.*,x.ROWID FROM table.PROJECT x
WHERE CONFIDENTIAL = 'Y' AND RESTRICTED = NULL
```

...etc

Desired result table (doesn't need to have 'Description', that's just shown for context):

```
+------------+--------------+-------------+--------------------------------------------------+
| RESTRICTED | CONFIDENTIAL | Num records |                   Description                    |
+------------+--------------+-------------+--------------------------------------------------+
| {any}      | {any}        |         586 | any status, i.e. "all records"                   |
|            |              |             |                                                  |
| Y          | {any}        |         191 | Restricted, assumed not confidential             |
| Y          | N            |         184 | Restricted, not confidential                     |
| Y          | Y            |           7 | Restricted, is confidential                      |
| Y          | NULL         |           0 | Restricted, assumed not confidential             |
|            |              |             |                                                  |
| N          | {any}        |         395 | Not restricted, any confidential                 |
| N          | N            |         329 | Not restricted, not confidential                 |
| N          | Y            |           7 | Not restricted, is confidential                  |
| N          | NULL         |           0 | Not restricted, assumed not confidential         |
|            |              |             |                                                  |
| {any}      | N            |         513 | Assumed not restricted, not confidential         |
| {any}      | Y            |           7 | Assumed not restricted, is confidential          |
| {any}      | NULL         |          66 | Assumed not restricted, assumed not confidential |
|            |              |             |                                                  |
| NULL       | {any}        |           0 | Assumed not restricted, assumed not confidential |
+------------+--------------+-------------+--------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: For the desired output you are showing also some combinations with zero records (e.g. `Y` with `NULL`, `N` with `NULL` and `NULL` with `{any}`), but not all (e.g. `NULL` with `Y`, `N` or `NULL`). Is this selective treatment of zero row count an important part of your goal?

Comment: @Hilarion Yes it's important to know which combinations return zero records. Not having all combinations present in the example is an oversight (and provides of a demonstration for why seeking a non-manual solution is a good idea!).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I'd suggest editing the question, to correct the desired result, so all new contributors can address the full problem easily.

Comment: @Hilarion, so added.

Comment: Note for watchers: I've been pulled away from this project for a couple of days and unable to evaluate the answers thus far. I'll be coming back to it quick as I can.

Answer (score 2):

There's a tool in Oracle DB specifically for this scenario.
It's the `CUBE` operation of the [`GROUP BY`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6__I2182483) clause. We can use it here, with some help of [`GROUPING`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/GROUPING.html) function, to distinguish between *raw* `NULL` value and the `NULL` value representing a summary. (The query would be much more simple, if the `restricted` and `confidential` columns would not be nullable.)

It goes like this:

```
SELECT DECODE(GROUPING(t.restricted), 1, '{any}', t.restricted) AS restricted,
       DECODE(GROUPING(t.confidential), 1, '{any}', t.confidential) AS confidential,
       COUNT(*)
  FROM project t
 GROUP BY CUBE(t.restricted, t.confidential);
```

Some explanation:
The use of `CUBE` modifies the `GROUP BY` behavior, to not only do the aggregations for groups determined by given columns, but also to create summary groups (basically by eliminating all combinations of columns from the grouping criteria, including elimination of all, for a total summary).
The summary groups will have `NULL` for the value in the columns eliminated from the summary. If that column could have a `NULL` value, then Oracle DB will be able to distinguish between a normal group with a `NULL` value and a summary group. You can access that information, using `GROUPING` function, which will return 1 if this is a summary group for a column given to that function and 0 otherwise.

**Edit:**
An important remark: The query will not (same as with normal `GROUP BY`) return all combinations of `restricted` and `confidential`, just those, which actually occur in data (and the summaries), so to produce those (with zero count), you'd have to adjust the query.
You have listed some of such cases, e.g.:

```
+------------+--------------+-------------+--------------------------------------------------+
| RESTRICTED | CONFIDENTIAL | Num records |                   Description                    |
+------------+--------------+-------------+--------------------------------------------------+
| Y          | NULL         |           0 | Restricted, assumed not confidential             |
| N          | NULL         |           0 | Not restricted, assumed not confidential         |
| NULL       | {any}        |           0 | Assumed not restricted, assumed not confidential |
+------------+--------------+-------------+--------------------------------------------------+
```

but not all, e.g.:

```
+------------+--------------+-------------+
| RESTRICTED | CONFIDENTIAL | Num records |
+------------+--------------+-------------+
| NULL       | N            |           0 |
| NULL       | Y            |           0 |
| NULL       | NULL         |           0 |
+------------+--------------+-------------+
```

**Edit 2:**
To cover for the zero counts in the result, you could try something like this (notice `SUM` on a custom column replacing `COUNT` of rows):

```
WITH v AS (
  SELECT 'Y' AS val FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'N' AS val FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT NULL AS val FROM DUAL
),
s AS (
  SELECT id, restricted, confidential, 1 AS cnt
    FROM project
  UNION ALL
  SELECT NULL, r.val, c.val, 0
    FROM v r
   CROSS JOIN v c
)
SELECT DECODE(GROUPING(s.restricted), 1, '{any}', s.restricted) AS restricted, 
       DECODE(GROUPING(s.confidential), 1, '{any}', s.confidential) AS confidential, 
       SUM(s.cnt) AS cnt
  FROM s
 GROUP BY CUBE(s.restricted, s.confidential)
```

It will however list all zero rows, not just those you listed as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`CUBE`](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/rollup-cube-grouping-functions-and-grouping-sets) in the grouping:

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE project ( restricted, confidential ) AS
  SELECT 'Y',  'Y'  FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <=   7 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Y',  'N'  FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 184 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Y',  NULL FROM DUAL WHERE 1 = 0             UNION ALL
  SELECT 'N',  'Y'  FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <=   7 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'N',  'N'  FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 329 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'N',  NULL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <=  59 UNION ALL
  SELECT NULL, 'Y'  FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <=   1 UNION ALL
  SELECT NULL, 'N'  FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <=   2 UNION ALL
  SELECT NULL, NULL FROM DUAL WHERE 1 = 0;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT CASE GROUPING( restricted )
       WHEN 1 THEN 'any'
       ELSE restricted
       END AS restricted,
       CASE GROUPING( confidential )
       WHEN 1 THEN 'any'
       ELSE confidential
       END AS confidential, COUNT(*)
FROM   project
GROUP BY CUBE( restricted, confidential )
ORDER BY 1 NULLS FIRST, 2 NULLS FIRST;
```

**Output**:

```
RESTRICTED  CONFIDENTIAL    COUNT(*)
----------  ------------    --------
 -          N               2
 -          Y               1
 -          any             3
N            -              59
N           N               329
N           Y               7
N           any             395
Y           N               184
Y           Y               7
Y           any             191
any          -              59
any         N               515
any         Y               15
any         any             589
```

**Query 2**: To get all combinations:

```
WITH options ( value ) AS (
  SELECT 'Y' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'N' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT NULL FROM DUAL
)
SELECT CASE GROUPING( r.value )
       WHEN 1 THEN 'any'
       ELSE r.value
       END AS restricted,
       CASE GROUPING( c.value )
       WHEN 1 THEN 'any'
       ELSE c.value
       END AS confidential,
       COUNT( p.n )
FROM   options r
       CROSS JOIN options c
       LEFT OUTER JOIN ( SELECT p.*, 1 AS n FROM project p ) p
       ON     ( p.restricted   = r.value OR ( p.restricted   IS NULL AND r.value IS NULL ) )
          AND ( p.confidential = c.value OR ( p.confidential IS NULL AND c.value IS NULL ) )
GROUP BY CUBE( r.value, c.value )
ORDER BY 1 NULLS FIRST, 2 NULLS FIRST;
```

**Output**:

```
RESTRICTED  CONFIDENTIAL    COUNT(P.N)
----------  ------------    ----------
 -           -              0
 -          N               2
 -          Y               1
 -          any             3
N            -              59
N           N               329
N           Y               7
N           any             395
Y            -              0
Y           N               184
Y           Y               7
Y           any             191
any          -              59
any         N               515
any         Y               15
any         any             589
```

Comment: There seems to be missing the total summary row (with `any` and `any`) from your output. The query itself seems fine.

Comment: @Hilarion Thanks, just missed the last row of the output when copy/pasting.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't an ordinary aggregation do the job? For example:

```
SQL> with project (id, confidential, restricted) as
  2    (select 1, 'y', null  from dual union all
  3     select 2, 'n', null  from dual union all
  4     select 3, null, 'y'  from dual union all
  5     select 4, null, null from dual union all
  6     select 5, 'n', 'n'   from dual union all
  7     select 6, 'y', 'y'   from dual union all
  8     select 7, 'y', 'n'   from dual union all
  9     select 8, 'y', 'y'   from dual
 10    )
 11  select restricted, confidential, count(*)
 12  from project
 13  group by restricted, confidential;

R C   COUNT(*)
- - ----------
             1
y y          2
  y          1
n y          1
  n          1
y            1
n n          1

7 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: This does not seem to calculate summaries, e.g. will not also count how many rows are there with "Y" for `confidential` regardless of the `restricted` value (i.e. the "{any}" rows from the desired output given in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `cross join` to generate the rows and then a `left join` and `group by` to calculate the counts:

```
with vals as (
      select 'Y' as val from dual union all
      select 'N' as val from dual union all
      select NULL as val from dual
     )
select vc.val as confidential, vr.val as restricted,
       count(p.rowid)
from vals vc cross join
     vals vr left join
     table p
     on (p.confidential = vc.val or p.confidential is null and vc.val is null) and
        (p.restricted = vr.val or p.restricted is null and vr.val is null)
group by vc.val, vr.val;
```

Comment: This does not seem to calculate summaries, e.g. will not also count how many rows are there with "Y" for `confidential` regardless of the `restricted` value (i.e. the "{any}" rows from the desired output given in the question.